# Running around 15 python scripts at once

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am scraping live data from an exchange for various assets (around 15). So, I have the script, which i'm planning on copying 15 times and replace the necessary fields for each asset (API call etc) how would one run all 15 scripts at once ?

From going through a few posts I can see opening multiple CMD is an option, in my case however that's quite a few windows. 
Is there a script manger app or something that can process all scripts ?

EDIT:
When i said 'replace the necessary fields' I mean replace the asset name in the API call

Comment: You tagged this `multiprocessing` and that is the obvious answer. Consider a pool of workers. When you say "replace the necessary fields" I don't know what that means for sure, but it sounds like you should convert the script to a function call. Then you invoke the pool with something like `pool.map(my_function, [(tuple of params), (tuple of params), ...]. Look at `multiprocessing` examples to get something concrete.

Answer (score 0):

@tdelaney is right on. Wrap the code you are wanting to run multiple times in a function with any variables you need, and pass the function and all 15 variables to pool.map. I modified an example from the Python docs to apply to your case. This example case just adds two numbers.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def your_function(args):
    return args[0] + args[1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(15)  # pool with 15 processes
    args = [(x, x) for x in range(15)]  # 15 argument tuples
    print(pool.map(your_function, args))
```

Output:

```
>>> [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28]
```